# Replace characters on the end of a string?

Tags: python

I am working in Python and I have a string such as `"world's" and "states.'"` where I want to check if the last letter of the word is an alphabet, and if not, remove it. I have the following code:

```
if word[-1].isalpha():
    print word
else:
    print word[:-1]
```

but I also want to be able to remove two (or more) non alphabetic characters. I know I need some kind of loop.

Answer (score 4):

Try a loop:

```
def rstripNotalpha(s):
    while not s[-1].isalpha():
        s = s[:-1]
    return s

s = "'foo.-,'"
print(rstripNotalpha(s))
```

Output:

```
"'foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

String's `rstrip` function optionally takes a list of characters to remove.

```
rstrip(...)
    S.rstrip([chars]) -> string or unicode

    Return a copy of the string S with trailing whitespace removed.
    If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
    If chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before stripping
```

Comment: That's true but `chars` is a blacklist. A whitelist would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Or a good old regexp:

```
import re
p = re.compile('(.*\w)([^\w]*)')
m = p.match(word)
print m.group(1)
```